# Track portfolio value over time with value_history model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a stock portfolio app and am trying to figure out a way to store the values of my portfolio over time. I've read about ActiveModel::Dirty and wondered if this seems to do this.

```
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :positions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :movements, through: :positions

  belongs_to :user

  validates :name,
            presence: { message: "must be given." }

  def portfolio_value
    amount = positions.collect{|position| 
             position.quanity * position.value }.sum.round(2)
  end

end
```

My question though is what is it doing under the hood. Is it creating an array storing all the past values or simply storing the previous value. I want to be able to store at least 6 months worth of data and wondered if this is the best choice for scaling up to that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The [Papertrail gem](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) can be useful for implementing track changes on models.

Comment: I've read about paper_clip but from my understanding, it's for logging errors or versioning database models. Is it too much if I'm just looking to store values to plot on a graph?